# What is PROTECTED_ACTION and ASSESSMENT_NAME?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I apologise if this is a stupid question, but I have no clue what to put for these values.

```
define('SITE_KEY', '**************************');
define('TOKEN', $reportToken);
define('ASSESSMENT_NAME', 'What do I put here?');
define('PROTECTED_ACTION', 'What do I put here?');
define('PARENT_PROJECT', 'projects/project-name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, it would seem that you are trying to build and [create an assessment](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment#php) using reCAPTCHA Enterpise using PHP.

In terms of what is needed in ASSESSMENT_NAME and PROTECTED_ACTION, I would suggest reviewing the following documents to help understand the API and SDK of reCAPTCHA:

1. reCAPTCHA PHP client library:
   https://github.com/google/recaptcha
2. Client Libraries > PHP Reference:
   https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.153.0/recaptchaenterprise/v1/recaptchaenterpriseserviceclient
3. REST Resource: projects.assessments
   https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.assessments